# Where do these aliens come from?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrival

I've seen *Arrival* but there are things that are not explained. In the movie, the aliens come from somewhere using the spaceship called 'shell'. Where do they come from, from what planet/galaxy? And why are humans chosen to help them?

**[source](http://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Heptapod)**

Comment: Does it matter? The movie makes no attempt to explain it and it is hard to see why it would make any difference to anything we do see.

Comment: Yes, It matters (at least for me)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing in the movie suggests where they came from or where they call home, so we don't know that part.

They came to us because they foresaw that they would need our help in the future.  Because they can see that we were the ones who will help them, they came to us.  This issue has been discussed before; probably one of the best explanations for the heptapods' motivations I've seen is Eldothiad's answer here:

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152279/in-arrival-why-wasnt-this-event-avoided

Comment: Are there any movie featuring the very same alien?

Comment: No, this movie is stand-alone, although it is based on a short story by Ted Chiang entitled "[The Story of Your Life](https://www.amazon.ca/Stories-Your-Life-Others-Chiang/dp/1101972122)"  I haven't read it myself, but I think the movie *added* material to fill out the running time, so I don't know if it has anything else to add.